# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: java, mysql

Inserting data from java form into MySql database Details in table personal

but I getting the error Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I'm using Netbeans 6.9, MySql 5.6

I have declared ID as int with primary key, Phone and mobile as int and all other as char.

```
 import java.sql.*;
 import javax.swing.*;

  public class Personal_Details extends javax.swing.JFrame{

   Connection conn;
   String url;
   Statement stmt;
   ResultSet rs;

  public javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel tableview;
    public Personal_Details() {
    initComponents();
          tableview= new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel();
          jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable(tableview);
           tableview.addColumn("ID");
           tableview.addColumn("Name");
           tableview.addColumn("Address");
           tableview.addColumn("Gender");
           tableview.addColumn("Education");
           tableview.addColumn("Phone");
           tableview.addColumn("Mobie");
           tableview.addColumn("DOB");
           jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);
      try{
      url = "jdbc:mysql:///Details";
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","anand");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();

        }catch(Exception e){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
    }

    private void btnSubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    {
    try{
    stmt.executeUpdate("insert into
    personal(ID,Name,Address,Gender,Education,Phone,Mobile,DOB) values
    ("+tfIDNo.getText()+
         ",'"+tfName.getText()+"','"+tfAddress.getText()+"','"+tfGender.getText()+"','"
         +                                                                        
      "','"+tfEducation.getText()+"',"+tfPhone.getText()+","+tfMobile.getText()+",'"+
     tfDob.getText()+"')");


   rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from personal where ID="+tfIDNo.getText()+" and   
   Name='"+tfName.getText()+"' and Addess='"+tfAddress.getText()+"'"
         + "' and Gender='"+tfGender.getText()+"' and  
    Education='"+tfEducation.getText()+"' and phone="+tfPhone.getText()+" "
         + " and Mobile="+tfMobile.getText()+" and DOB='"+tfDob.getText()+"'");
    }catch(Exception e){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
   }
   }
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Personal_Details().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JButton btnClear;
private javax.swing.JButton btnClose;
private javax.swing.JButton btnSubmit;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblAddress;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblDob;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblDobFormat;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblEducation;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblEnterYourDetails;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblGender;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblIDNo;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblMobile;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblName;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblPhone;
private javax.swing.JTextField tfAddress;
private javax.swing.JTextField tfDob;
private javax.swing.JTextField tfEducation;
private javax.swing.JTextField tfGender;
private javax.swing.JTextField tfIDNo;
private javax.swing.JTextField tfMobile;
private javax.swing.JTextField tfName;
private javax.swing.JTextField tfPhone;
}


  Database - ID, Name, Address, Gender, Education, Phone, Mobile, DOB.
```

Comment: Hello Prince. Try to use `PreparedStatement`. It's almost sure your problem will be solved.

Comment: Hi, the shared code only describes the swing table in the UI and does not explains the persisting logic, please add your database persisting logic in the code as well as the problem seems to be in that logic.

Answer (score 1):

Correct your `INSERT` statement with this:

```
String s = "insert into 
            personal(ID, Name,Address, Gender, Education, Phone, Mobile, DOB) 
            values (" + "'" + t.getText() + "','" + t.getText() + "','" 
            + t.getText() + "','" + t.getText() + "','" + t.getText() + "','"
            + t.getText() + "','" + t.getText() + "','" + t.getText() + "')";
```

replace my `t.getText()` with yours and now it should works.

**Note:** But i suggest to you to use `PreparedStatement` istead of `Statement` and use placeholders **`?`**.
This solution is more clean and more safe!([**`SQL injection`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)) and more human-readable.

Answer (score 0):

@Prince
Use PreparedStatement instead of simple Statement as this will increase performance of your program. Like this:

```
PreparedStatement Pstatement=Your_Connection_Object.prepareStatement("insert 
into mydb.Stock values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

            //Specifying the values of it's parameter
Pstatement.setString(1,tfIDNo.getText());
Pstatement.setString(2,tfName.getText());
Pstatement.setString(3,tfAddress.getText());
Pstatement.setString(4,tfGender.getText());
Pstatement.setString(5,tfEducation.getText());
Pstatement.setString(6,tfPhone.getText());
Pstatement.setString(7,tfMobile.getText());
Pstatement.setString(8,tfDob.getText());

Pstatement.executeUpdate();
```

As you can see, we are passing parameter (?) for the values. Its value will be set by calling the setter methods of PreparedStatement.

Comment: Hi, your code does not answer the specific problem (even if it might have not been clear).